# How to calculate the return from a mutual fund?

Tags: mutual-funds, calculation, rate-of-return, compound-interest

How do I calculate the return from a mutual fund invested as a monthly SIP of Rs. 5000 over a period of 3 years at a return rate of 20.4% per annum?

The projected amount for the same is calculated by this [website](https://groww.in/mutual-funds/mirae-asset-india-opportunities-fund-direct-growth). However, I am not being able to calculate the same myself by hand.

[image]

---

I used [SIP calculator](https://sipcalculator.in/) which returns **Rs. 249660**

[image]

A [recurring deposit calculator](http://rd-calculator.in/) returns **Rs. 242754**

[image]

Comment: what value do you get when you try to do the calculation?

Comment: I'm not sure what "return" you're looking for. You're already given the return of the fund, and you're contributing the same amount periodically, so return on what?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Updated the original post

Comment: @DStanley I tried to back calculate the return they report. However, as my post says, I couldn't reproduce the same.

Comment: The rate appears to be rounded in display. Use 20.41% e.g. in Excel `=FV((1+20.41/100)^(1/12)-1,36,-5000)` produces 239059.  All explained in my answer.

Comment: Your second SIP calculator is using a different calculation, i.e. in Excel `=FV(20.4/100/12,36,-5000,0,1)` producing 249660. The main differences are that the interest rate here is nominal compounded monthly rather than [effective annual rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation), and the payments are at month-start rather than month-end. Presumably the Mirae calculator uses month-end payments because the lump sum calculates from month-start and they don't want a SIP payment at the same time as the lump sum, but it means the last SIP payment accrues no interest.

Comment: The third calculator uses an effective annual rate and month-start payments, i.e. in Excel `=FV((1+20.4/100)^(1/12)-1,36,-5000,0,1)` producing 242754.

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't see the fund in your screenshot, but here is the one from the web link.

[image]

The one-year return can be calculated like so.

[image]

Also using a formula

```
a = d ((1 + r)^n - 1)/r
```

where

```
a is the future amount
d is the monthly payment (paid at month-end)
n is the number of months
r is the monthly interest rate
```

The annual interest rate is 14.4%

```
r = (1 + 14.4/100)^(1/12) - 1 = 0.011274

n = 12
d = 5000

a = d ((1 + r)^n - 1)/r = 63863.84
```

The same in Excel

[image]

The 3 year result is a little out, presumably some rounding inaccuracy

```
r = (1 + 19.3/100)^(1/12) - 1 = 0.0148146

n = 36
d = 5000

a = d ((1 + r)^n - 1)/r =  235556.95
```

A 3 year annualised return of 19.26% obtains the website figure, shown below.

```
r = (1 + 19.26/100)^(1/12) - 1 = 0.0147862

n = 36
d = 5000

a = d ((1 + r)^n - 1)/r = 235431.40
```

I would guess the interest rate in the calculations is 19.26% but the website shows the figure rounded to one decimal place, as 19.3%.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem is that they are using historical returns, that means that they are using.

- 1.8% for one year
- 20.4% for 3 years.

But you aren't modeling a 180,000 investment for three years. You have a 5,000 investment for 36 months another 5,000 for 35 months...

You have to know the interest rates for each of the 36 months....but you don't know them

Comment: Not sure I understood. How do I know the interest rates for each of the 36 months?

Comment: I added a few words to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating SIP is very easy. You can visit my site http://easysipcalculator.com/ and enter the required details like monthly investment, no of years you are going to invest and what is the expected return rate. 
[Home page - enter the details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwtVs.png)

Then click on calculate,

You will get the projection of return and detailed summary report.
[Projected return vs invested capital](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jT2G.png)

[pie chart and all the good stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTjDG.png)

Comment: AFAIU, OP is not asking for web link to calculate returns. They are expecting method or formula to calculate it.